# How do I protect all worksheet in an Excel workbook with a single click?

Tags: excel, vba

I have around 25 worksheets in my workbook (Excel spreadsheet).
Is there a way I can protect all the 25 worksheets in single click ? or this feature is not available and I will have to write a VBA code to accomplish this. I need very often to protect all sheets and unprotect all sheets and doing individually is time consuming

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to do it without using VBA.  If you are interested in a VBA solution, here is the code:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim pwd as String

pwd = "" ' Put your password here
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Protect Password:=pwd
Next ws
```

Unprotecting is virtually the same:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim pwd as String

pwd = "" ' Put your password here
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Unprotect Password:=pwd
Next ws
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't think there's a button to do it, but it's simple enough code:

For Each protSheet In Worksheets
  protSheet.Protect Password := "boo"
Next protSheet

Answer (score 3):

You can protect all worksheets from user changes but still allow VBA scripts to make changes with the "UserInterfaceOnly" option.  This workaround lets you run any VBA script on the worksheets without having to protect and unprotect each time:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim pwd as String

pwd = "" ' Put your password here
or Each ws In Worksheets
   ws.Protect Password:=pwd, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Next ws
```

Unprotecting is the same as the solution offered by Ben Hoffstein:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim pwd as String

pwd = "" ' Put your password here
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Unprotect Password:=pwd
Next ws
```

You can access this macro with a button/shortcut.  In Excel 2010 you right-click on the Quick Access toolbar and select "Customize Quick Access Toolbar".  In the drop down menu to choose commands, select "Macros".  Then click the VBA script you created to protect (or unprotect).  Finally click the "Add > >" button and then "OK" to save it.

Answer (score 1):

You can protect the workbook rather than each sheet and this will stop changes being made across the entire workbook

Comment: This is a very different set of protection, and won't solve the question.  Protecting the workbook only protects certain features about the workbook (such as moving tabs around) - it does not do Sheet Protection on all sheets as people tend to think - you need to protect sheets separately.  You may also want to use Workbook Protection if you want to protect those parts of the workbook as well, but that's a separate consideration.